# Does this equation have a solution in $\mathbb{Q}_{11}$ and in $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

In the department where I am studying there was a talk on Hilbert Symbols and Hasse principle.

The orator asked us the following question on which I am not able to make any progress. So, I am asking for help here.

> Question : Does $f: 7 x^2 + 4y^2 =z^2 $ have a solution in (i) $\mathbb{Q}_{11}$ and in (ii) $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Attempt: I am not able to make any progress on this question. I don't think there is a point using hit and trial method here. I have not studied any algebraic number theory but I thought I should try the question. My background in Algebra is strong.

Can you please let me know how should I approach the solution? Which results should I use?

Thanks!

Comment: If it was a talk on Hilbert symbols and the Hasse principle, the equation  must have been $7x^2 + 4y^2 = z^2$.

Comment: I strongly second @franzlemmermeyer's observation that the equation is $7x^2+4y^2=z^2$, that is, there's no $4xy^2$ term, since solvability-or-not of the quadratic equation is exactly whether the Hilbert symbol is $+1$ or $-1$.

Comment: @paulgarrett Ok, I checked my notes again and I have written the correct statement but The talk was very badly delivered and orator's handwriting was also not legible so  I am editing the question since so many people here are saying that it should be $4 y^2$.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer Please have a look at my above comment.

Comment: For $p\ne 2,7$ contrusct a solution to $7x^2+4y^2=1$ in $\Bbb{F}_p$ (how many values do $7x^2$ and $1-4y^2$ take $\bmod p$?) then lift with Hensel lemma

Comment: Part (i) is just the case $p=11$ of part (ii). Also, there are trivial solutions with $x=0$ and $z=\pm 2y$ (for the corrected equation with $4y^2$). So, one should require $x \ne 0$.

Comment: @reuns Can you please write a complete answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COMMENT.-Because of the diophantine equation $f(x)=7x^2+4y^2-z^2=0$ has the integer solution $(x,y,z)=(2,3,8)$, we can say (because $\mathbb Q$ is embedding in $\mathbb Q_p$) that $f(x)=0$ has solution for all prime $p$. However I understand the purpose of this problem is giving an exercise of verification for a particular example of Hasse principle. It is, in fact, mainly an exercise of working in $\mathbb Q_p$